# Try to modify gcc created *.s file, and some strange thing happened

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, stack

This is my source code **a.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 1000 

int p[N] = {0};
int a[N] = {0};

void main(){
    long int i;
    int acc;
    time_t t_start, t_end;

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        a[i] = i;        
    }

    t_start = clock();

    acc = p[0] = a[0];
    for(i = 1; i < N; ++i){
        acc = acc + a[i];
        p[i] = acc;
    }

    t_end = clock();

    printf("%d\ntime: %f ms\n", p[N - 1], ((double)t_end - t_start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);//output the result of p[999] and the execution time
    return;
}
```

and I used gcc -S command created **a.s**:

```
    .file   "a.c"
    .globl  p
    .bss
    .align 32
    .type   p, @object
    .size   p, 4000
p:
    .zero   4000
    .globl  a
    .align 32
    .type   a, @object
    .size   a, 4000
a:
    .zero   4000
    .section    .rodata
.LC2:
    .string "%d\ntime: %f ms\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    $0, -24(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, a(,%rax,4)
    addq    $1, -24(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpq    $999, -24(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    call    clock
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movl    a(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, p(%rip)
    movl    p(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)
    movq    $1, -24(%rbp)
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    a(,%rax,4), %eax
    addl    %eax, -28(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    -28(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, p(,%rax,4)
    addq    $1, -24(%rbp)
.L4:
    cmpq    $999, -24(%rbp)
    jle .L5
    call    clock
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    cvtsi2sdq   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
    cvtsi2sdq   -16(%rbp), %xmm1
    subsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
    divsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movl    p+3996(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    printf
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1083129856
    .align 8
.LC1:
    .long   0
    .long   1093567616
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I noticed some interesting lines of codes start from **.L5**:

```
.L5:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    a(,%rax,4), %eax
    addl    %eax, -28(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    -28(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, p(,%rax,4)
    addq    $1, -24(%rbp)
```

It seems that -28(%rbp) is useless.

so, I made some adjustment like this:

```
.L5:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    a(,%rax,4), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, p(,%rax,4)
    addq    $1, -24(%rbp)
```

I used original **a.s** created **a1.out** and used my modified **a.s** file created **a2.out**.

Then I executed **a1.out** and **a2.out**.

**What surprised me is that I got totally different result of p[999]!!!**

Did I missed something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes - a few instructions previous: `movl %eax, -28(%rbp)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have any comment on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: reply to harper, sir, I am just trying to achieve better performance by decrease store/load operations.

Comment: reply to Brett Hale, sir, it seems like that **-28(%rbp)** is only be used in **.L5** loop, and its only function is storing **%edx**. Since I have use `movl %edx, p(,%rax,4)` replaced `movl -28(%rbp), %edx` and `movl %edx, p(,%rax,4)`, this instruction `movl %eax, -28(%rbp)` seems have no use at all.

Comment: Instead of spending all that time analyzing assembly output, why don't you just ask gcc to *optimize*? (`gcc -O2` or even `gcc -O3`).

Comment: By the way, the bug you introduced probably has to do with not initializing `%edx` properly. (Also: to direct a reply to someone, use `@someone`

Comment: @rici Thanks for your help, I forgot to initialize `%edx`. After I add `movl $0, %edx` before `.L5`, the program executed accurately. And when I compared my modified program's execution speed with 'gcc -o3' created program's execution speed(it still use `-28(%rbp)`), the result is inspiring. My program executed faster!   BTW: I am intended to learn something in compilers, so I tried these modifications. Thanks for your help, @rici!